# AWS SQL Server 2016 Restoring 2 Databases Error Message

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am testing to see if a SQL Server server based program can also work on AWS Cloud Server with 2016 SQL Server on the Amazon server. In order for me to test it, I need to restore 2 databases.
The first one eventually restored fine once i figured it out...restoring the database from my S3 "bucket" BAK file.
So then I tried to restore the 2nd database, using the same restore stored proceudre, and get this message:

> [2017-12-28 02:44:22.320] The file 'D:\rdsdbdata\DATA\smsystemdata.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'amwsys'.
>   [2017-12-28 02:44:22.320] File 'sm_system_data' cannot be restored to 'D:\rdsdbdata\DATA\smsystemdata.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

I can't find where to use the WITH MOVE because it won't let me restore it interactively through the Management Studio restore menu; instead I have to give it a stored procedure command:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
    @restore_db_name='sample99', 
    @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::lighthouse-chicago/sample999.bak';
```

And each time it tells me it can't restore it because it's going to overwrite the first database's files.

Much thanks
bill

Comment: How many do you have .BAK files?  Do you want restore 2 databases from 1 .BAK file(sample999.bak)?

Comment: I'm trying to restore 2 .BAK files. One is a database called AMWSYS.BAK (restored fine) and the second is called SAMPLE999.BAK. When I first restore AMWSYS.BAK (successfully) and then try to restore SAMPLE999, the SAMPLE 999 errors out saying that D:\rdsdata\Data\smsystemdata.mdf is being used and cannot be overwritten. When I reverse the order and install SAMPLE999.BAK first, that restores fine but then I can't restore AMWSYS.BAK. Gives me the same message.

Comment: Was you backup backup 2 times from 1 dababase?  (ex.  databasename: foo).   AWS RDS has many restrictions for administration features.  So I'm worry about you are in this case/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are stuck in RDS's restriction.
I had the similar problem as you.  Multiple restore from one DB instance is impossible at RDS.

Here is RDS's restriction you may encounter.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

> You can't restore a backup file to the same DB instance that was used
>   to create the backup file. Instead, restore the backup file to a new
>   DB instance. Renaming the database is not a workaround for this
>   limitation.
>
> You can't restore the same backup file to a DB instance multiple
>   times. That is, you can't restore a backup file to a DB instance that
>   already contains the database that you are restoring. Renaming the
>   database is not a workaround for this limitation.

If you are in this case, you can't use .BAK file.  To avoid it, you should create DB instance with DML and import table data.